# If-else statement in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

i have a problem with the next question, i need to solve it by using if/else, i wrote the code but i don't know if it's the solve of the question or not:

Write a program in which the user enters the coordinates of the black pawns (a, b) on the chessboard.

The program must determine whether the pawn may move to get to one field (c, d):
1. In the ordinary move;
2. When it "hit" piece or pawn opponent.

Note: Black pawn move on the board from the bottom up.

```
char CoordinY;
int CoordinX;

if (CoordinY > 'b' && CoordinX <= 1 && CoordinX>8)
{
    cout << "Error . . . \n";
}
else
{
    if (CoordinX >= 2 && CoordinX <= 8 && CoordinY == 'a' || CoordinY == 'b'*)  
    {
        // arbitrary move:
        cout << "will not get to the field (c, d) in the ordinary move.\n"; 
        // when it "hits" enemy's figure or pawn
        cout << "will not get to the field (c, d) when ше hit a figure or pawn opponent.\n"; 
    }
    else if (CoordinX>1 && CoordinX < 8 && CoordinY == 'b')
    {
        // arbitrary move
        cout << "will not get to the field (c, d) in the ordinary move.\n";
        // when it "hits" enemy's figure or pawn
        cout << "will not get to the field (c, d) when it hit a figure or pawn opponent.\n";
    }
```

Comment: That first condition (`CoordinX > 'b' && CoordinX <= 1 && CoordinX>8`) doesn't make any sense. First of all, is `CoordinX` a character or an integer? Second of all the value can never be less than or equal to `1` *and* at the same time be larger than `8`. I think you need to go back to the chapter of the book that discusses the logical operators, and work through that again.

Comment: i edited the question, sorry for mistake 
int CoordinX;
char CoordinY;

Comment: I believe you should take arbitrary coordinates - "a" and "b" are variables - not coordinates whose values are `'a` and `'b'`. If you have a pawn in (a, b), its potential moves are to (a, b+1); (a, b + 2); (a + 1, b + 1); and (a -1 , b + 1).

Comment: The first condition still doesn't make any sense, no matter the value of `CoordinX` the condition will never be true. Also, remember that the `&&` operator has higher precedence than the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the answer I assume the following classic chess board and the fact that I am moving **white** pawn:

[image: Chess board]

It is important because in your problem definition, blacks are moving bottom up, which is incorrect.

In my example, I will use the following variables:

```
char a, c; int b, d; // E2 - E4 is: a = 'e', b = 2, c = 'e', d = 4.
```

### Arbitrary move

Where can a pawn go with an arbitrary move in chess?

1. One step ahead
2. Two steps ahead if it is standing at row 2

So, in general, a pawn at `(a; b)` can move to `(c; d)`, if they stand in the same row (`a == c`) AND if it is one step ahead or two steps ahead for `b` equal to 2.

So, let's implement it:

```
if (a == c && (d - b == 1 || (d - b == 2 && b == 2)))
    cout << "Abitrary move: YES";
} else {
    cout << "Arbitrary move: NO";
}
```

### Attack

A pawn can move with an attack if only an enemy is standing in the next row, one cell to the left or to the right:

```
if ((c == a + 1 || c == a - 1) && (d - b == 1))
    cout << "Attack: YES";
} else {
    cout << "Attack: NO";
}
```

**Note** that this solution is not working for the case which is called [**en passant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant) (is it more well-known as "битое поле" or "взятие на проходе" in Russian).

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution in pseudocode:

```
if (d == b - 1)   // destination is one square up
  if (c == a)     // pawn is on a square in the same column as destination
    return true;  // yes, pawn can move forwards to destination
  if (c == a - 1 || c == a + 1)  // destination is one square to left or right
    return true;  // yes, pawn can take a white pawn to move to destination
end if
return false
```

First we do the check which is true for both cases... is the destination only one step in front (note that in chess pawns can also move two squares on their first turn, but you didn't request that solution so I haven't added it)?

Next we check if the move is either straight ahead, or diagonal.

You might want to check that a,b c,d are all valid chess coordinates to start with, which would prevent illegal moves being marked as ok.

Edit: also I'm assuming that the bottom of the board has a larger 'y' coordinate than the top.  If the coordinates are reversed you would check for b + 1 in the first conditional.